# unable to set path for imagemagick in mac osx snow leopard for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard, wkhtmltopdf

imagemagic and wkhtml are available in users/mithin

I have tried setting the path in profile file.
This is the content of .profile :

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/mithin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/mithin/ImageMagick-6.6.7/bin:$PATH"
```

When I try to run "identify" in terminal it runs properly

And when I try to run my Ruby on rails project it gives error.

Similar things happen with "wkhtmltopdf"

in terminal it runs properly

but in ror output it gives :

> sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found

Can anyone please point my mistake ?

Comment: Are you trying to run the commands directly or through a plugin/gem such as Paperclip?

Comment: for wkhtml I am using direct system call.
for imagemagick I am using paperclip

Comment: I echoed the $path variable in terminal it properly lists all the path for Imagemagick and wkhtmltopdf 
But when I echo in the ROR project using the system command I don get the path for ImageMagick and wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Paperclip to find the commands outside of the default install location, add the following to the appropriate file within /config/environments/

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/Users/mithin/ImageMagick-6.6.7/bin"
```